# C++ How to change value of 2Dvector using reference to particular element?

Tags: c++, vector, reference

When I try to change the vector I reach same values. Please explain me how to solve this problem?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int &Give2DVectorRef(int i, int j, vector<vector<int>> &matrix) {
    return matrix.at(i).at(j);
}

int main() {
    vector<vector<int>> matrix{
        {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2, 2, 2}, {3, 3, 3, 3, 3}};
    int ref;
    ref = Give2DVectorRef(1, 3, matrix);
    ref = 55;

    cout << matrix.at(1).at(3) << endl; // print 2, but I expect 55
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: By defining a **real** reference : `int& ref = Give2DVectorRef(1, 3, matrix);`

Comment: @user1810087 your comment should be elevated to an answer since it does solve the OPs problem.

Comment: BTW: storing references/pointers to vector-elements is not a good idea. if you push/pop some other values into the container, you cannot relly on the reference/pointer anymore!

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is to change from

```
int ref;
ref = Give2DVectorRef(1, 3, matrix);
```

to

```
int &ref = Give2DVectorRef(1, 3, matrix);
```

(as @user1810087 already commented)

Here are some more comments on your code

- References to vector items can be dangerous.

Image

```
 int & ref = Give2DVectorRef(1, 3, matrix); 
 matrix[1].erase(matrix[1].begin()+2); //deletes the third item
 ref = 55; // Reference is no longer meaningful
```

This situation might also accour, if you insert an item before the location of the item referenced to.

- A matrix should not be stored as a vector of vectors. If you are using this construct in heavy numerical calculation you will face severe performance problems. A single vector of length (N*M) will be faster. Even better is the usage of a library such as [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page).
- If you are concerned about performance, the operator `.at` is slow in comparison to the operator `[]`.
- Avoid using `using namespace std;`

Comment: The reference could be invalidated any time an element is inserted even after the location referenced due to reallocations.